# How to Pass data/variables/objects to Zend_Controller_Plugin

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller-plugin

I am converting an old ZF app (its using an early ZF version where we used to do manual app loading/config in the index.php) to latest version, and in one of the plugin we are sending data directly to the plugin constructor

```
$front->registerPlugin(new My_Plugin_ABC($obj1, $obj2))
```

Now in the current version we can register a plugin by directly providing the details in the application.ini and I want to stay with this approach(registering using config file). So while testing, I noticed the the plugin constructor is called fairly early in the bootstrapping, so the only option I am left with is using Zend_Registry to store the data, and retrieve it in the hooks. So is it the right way? or are there any other better ways

**EDIT**
The plugin was actually managing ACL and Auth, and its receiving custom ACL and AUTH objects. Its using the preDispatch hook.

Comment: The answer will depend on three main things you will need to provide details about in your question : what are you *precisely* passing to this constructor, what is the purpose of the plugin, and at which state of the flow does it act (routeStartup, routeShutdown, predispatch, etc..) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so you could consider you ACL and Auth handlers as a some application resources, and be able to add configuration options for them in you application.ini

```
 //Create a Zend Application resource plugin for each of them

 class My_Application_Resource_Acl extends Zend_Application_Resource_Abstract {
     //notice the fact that a resource last's classname part is uppercase ONLY on the first letter (nobody nor ZF is perfect)
     public function init(){
         // initialize your ACL here
         // you can get configs set in application.ini with $this->getOptions()

         // make sure to return the resource, even if you store it in Zend_registry for a more convenient access
         return $acl;
     }
 }

 class My_Application_Resource_Auth extends Zend_Application_Resource_Abstract {
     public function init(){
         // same rules as for acl resource
         return $auth;
     }
 }

 // in your application.ini, register you custom resources path
 pluginpaths.My_Application_Resource = "/path/to/My/Application/Resource/"
 //and initialize them
 resources.acl =    //this is without options, but still needed to initialze
 ;resources.acl.myoption = myvalue // this is how you define resource options

 resources.auth =    // same as before

 // remove you plugin's constructor and get the objects in it's logic instead
 class My_Plugin_ABC extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
     public function preDispatch (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
          //get the objects
          $bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam("bootstrap");
          $acl = $bootstrap->getResource('acl');
          $auth = $bootstrap->getResource('auth');
          // or get them in Zend_Registry if you registered them in it

          // do your stuff with these objects

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acl is needed so many other places hence storing it in Zend_Registry is cool thing to do and since Zend_Auth is singleton so you can access it `$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance()` ; anywhere you like so no need for auth to be stored in registry .

Lastly if you have extended Zend_Acl class for your custom acl its better to make it also singleton . Then you can access acl `My_Acl::getInstance();`  where My_Acl is subclass of Zend_Acl  .